# Google Chrome autofilled PDF duplicates field data on print preview

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, pdf, printing

Hello I am banging my head along with the rest of my team trying to figure out an issue that we are running into when clicking the print icon in the Google Chrome PDF viewer with a pre-filled PDF form. When clicking the print icon it brings up the print preview and the entered data in the fields is duplicated across the same column that the fields are in (screen shots below). We basically pre-fill information for a particular client that was selected and pulled from our database. We take that information and build an adobe FDF string.

```
 Public Function BuildFDF(ByVal arrObj() As IBuildFDF, ByVal sPDF As String, ByVal bLock As Boolean) As String
        Dim i As Int32 = 0
        Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder

        'build header
        sb.Append("%FDF-1.2") : sb.Append(Chr(13))
        sb.Append("1 0 obj") : sb.Append(Chr(13))
        sb.Append("<<") : sb.Append(Chr(13))
        sb.Append("/FDF") : sb.Append(Chr(13))
        sb.Append("<< ") : sb.Append(Chr(13))
        sb.Append("/Fields") : sb.Append(Chr(13))
        sb.Append("[") : sb.Append(Chr(13))

        'create fdf from objects in the array
        For i = 0 To arrObj.Length - 1
            sb.Append(arrObj(i).BuildFDF(bLock))
        Next

        'build trailer
        sb.Append(Chr(13)) : sb.Append("]") : sb.Append(Chr(13))
        sb.Append("/F ") : sb.Append("(" & sPDF & ")")

        ' put a popup message warning that there is autopopulated fields

        sb.Append(Chr(13)) : sb.Append("/Status (There may be prepopulated fields on this form \(in bold type\). Please \ review.)")
        'End If
        sb.Append(Chr(13)) : sb.Append(">>")
        sb.Append(Chr(13)) : sb.Append(" >> ")
        sb.Append(Chr(13)) : sb.Append("endobj")
        sb.Append(Chr(13)) : sb.Append("trailer ")
        sb.Append(Chr(13)) : sb.Append("<<  /Root 1 0 R  >> ")
        sb.Append(Chr(13)) : sb.Append("%%EOF")

        Return sb.ToString


    End Function
```

We use **ABCPdf** to format the values in the FDF string. Then add the values to a list of key value pairs.

```
     Dim theFDF As Doc = New Doc() 'ABCPdf WebSupergoo
       Dim theDoc As Doc = New Doc() 'ABCPdf WebSupergoo
       Dim pdfFile As String = ""
       Dim theValues As String = ""
       Dim theLastID As Integer
       Dim theList As New Hashtable

Public Sub GetEasyFillData(ByVal sFDF As String, Optional ByVal spdf As String = "")
            Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
            theFDF.Read(encoding.GetBytes(sFDF))
            theLastID = Convert.ToInt32(theFDF.GetInfo(0, "Count"))

            For i As Integer = 0 To theLastID
                Dim theType As String
                theType = theFDF.GetInfo(i, "Type")
                If theType = "anno" Then
                    If theFDF.GetInfo(i, "SubType") = "Text" Then
                        Dim theCont As String
                        theCont = theFDF.GetInfo(i, "Contents")
                        theValues = theValues + theCont + vbCrLf + vbCrLf
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            For i As Integer = 0 To theLastID
                Dim theNumber As Integer
                theNumber = theFDF.GetInfoInt(i, "/FDF*/Fields*:Count")
                Dim j As Integer
                For j = 0 To theNumber - 1
                    Dim theName As String = theFDF.GetInfo(i, "/FDF*/Fields*[" & j & "]*/T:Text")
                    Dim theValue As String = theFDF.GetInfo(i, "/FDF*/Fields*[" & j & "]*/V:Text")
                    If theList.ContainsKey(theName) = False Then
                        theList.Add(theName, theValue)
                    End If

                Next
            Next

            'Set location of pdf form to fill
            If spdf = "" Then
                pdfFile = theFDF.GetInfo(1, "FDF*/F:Text").ToString
            Else
                pdfFile = spdf
            End If

        End Sub
```

We then read the pdf form into **theDoc** variable, get the field names of the newly acquired pdf, and populate them with the respective field values from the list of key value pairs.

```
Public Sub PopulatePDF()

        With theDoc
            .Read(pdfFile)
        End With

        Dim fieldNames As String() = theDoc.Form.GetFieldNames()
        Dim fieldName As String
        For Each fieldName In fieldNames
            Dim theField As Field = theDoc.Form(fieldName)
            If (theField IsNot Nothing) Then
                If (theList.ContainsKey(theField.Name) = False) Then
                    theList.Add(theField.Name, theField.Value)
                End If
                theField.Value = CStr(theList.Item(theField.Name))
            End If


        Next

    End Sub
```

We then write the data to the page:

```
Private Sub AddPDFToPage()
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        With response
            .ContentType = "application/pdf"
            .AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyPDF.PDF")
            '.AddHeader("content-length", theDoc.GetData.Length.ToString())
            .BinaryWrite(theDoc.GetData())
        End With
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

    End Sub
```

Please see screenshots of what is ocurring when we enter data into these fields

**Before clicking print preview**
[image: Before clicking print preview]

**After Print preview**
[image: After Print preview]

If anyone has any ideas on why this is happening, ant feedback would be greatly appreciated.